# Why is getBean() not working in my JavaFX + Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx

first post here.
I'm making a Java project for college. I'm using JavaFX for the UI + Spring Boot as Framework. I've just started learning how to use Spring Boot, and I'm relatively new to JavaFX as well. I've been following a series of videos by intelliJ to set up the app classes: [Reactive Spring Boot: Part 4: JavaFX Line Chart](https://youtu.be/01GTN2iXbd8)

Everything works until I try to add dependency injection in the StageInitializer class, and I'm clueless as to why this can cause an error. In particular, it's the fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean) line that causes issues. If I remove the line, it compiles just fine.

```
@Component
public class StageInitializer implements ApplicationListener<StageReadyEvent> {
    @Value("classpath:/sample.fxml")
    private Resource resource;
    private final String applicationTitle;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public StageInitializer(@Value("${spring.application.ui.title}") String applicationTitle,
                        ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationTitle = applicationTitle;
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(StageReadyEvent event) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(resource.getURL());
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean); // Line that causes the issue
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = event.getStage();
        stage.setTitle(applicationTitle);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 640, 360));
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
}
```

At first, I thought that this might be because I modularized the app too much between the StageInitializer, an FX class, and a SpringBootApplication class. However, I made a simpler version and got the error as well:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringApp extends Application {
    public static ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public static Parent root;
    public static Stage stage;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringApp.class);
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(SpringApp.class.getResource("/sample.fxml"));
    loader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);   // Line that causes the issue
    Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load(), 640, 360, false, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

This is the output of the console:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated 

in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Jun 07, 2021 9:57:07 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @42f2fb20'
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.0)
2021-06-07 21:57:09.045  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application using Java 16.0.1
2021-06-07 21:57:09.047  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-06-07 21:57:09.570  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-06-07 21:57:09.587  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-06-07 21:57:09.974  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-06-07 21:57:10.019  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.31.Final
2021-06-07 21:57:10.143  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-06-07 21:57:10.258  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-06-07 21:57:10.622  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-06-07 21:57:10.638  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
2021-06-07 21:57:11.201  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-06-07 21:57:11.214  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-06-07 21:57:11.338  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 3.084 seconds (JVM running for 4.332)
2021-06-07 21:57:11.340  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2021-06-07 21:57:11.342  INFO 15228 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
Exception in Application start method
2021-06-07 21:57:11.386  INFO 15228 --- [lication Thread] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-06-07 21:57:11.388  INFO 15228 --- [lication Thread] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-06-07 21:57:11.391  INFO 15228 --- [lication Thread] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.ppai.reservavisita.StageInitializer.onApplicationEvent(StageInitializer.java:44)
    at com.ppai.reservavisita.StageInitializer.onApplicationEvent(StageInitializer.java:18)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
    at com.ppai.reservavisita.ReservaVisitaFX.start(ReservaVisitaFX.java:20)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:474)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:447)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:446)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
```

I hope I've explained myself well enough, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using an actual implementation instead of using `applicationContext::getBean` I'm not sure it is picking the right method? Also is this the full stacktrace? It looks like it is missing a part of it (the part telling you what is wrong).

Comment: @M.Deinum Not sure what you mean by "an actual implementation". There is only one `ApplicationContext.getBean(Class<?>)` method, so the method reference is unambiguous (it wouldn't compile otherwise). (I agree the stack trace appears truncated.)

Comment: Although the correct method might be called, type information could be lost and a bean of the type couldn't be found or a wrong type being returned.

Comment: I "fixed" it by moving the Controller to the same package where the Spring application is located. Now I'm stuck because the Controller can't detect an autowired repo attribute, but that's out of the scope of this thread. Thanks for the help guys.